# How to add RichTextField to models.Model in a mezzanine application?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I need to allow public users to add articles using `RichTextEditor` in a mezzanine application, similarly to how admin pages allow `RichTextFields`. Is it possible to use `RichTextField` for non-admin pages?

Comment: Minor English fixes.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use it on the frontend. RichText is an abstract model which you simply inherit.

Example:

```
class Article(RichText):
    ... your article fields go here ...
```

Now, your Article Model will have a field "content" inherited from RichText and the set of its own fields.

I hope that helps.